# 'powershell.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command during run of pipline jenkins stage on non-master node

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to invoke a Powershell script with a path to script on a non-master node?
    I have a code, but it throws an error, although the script is executed separately not from the job

```
pipeline {
agent none
options {
    skipDefaultCheckout true
}   

 environment {
   PATH = "C:\\Windows\\System32"
}

parameters {
string(name: 'Machine', defaultValue: 'Server', description: '')    
}   

stages{
    stage('create new machine') {
                agent { label "$params.Machine" }
                steps {
                    script {                
              powershellCmd("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\CreateQAXml.ps1")
                    }
                }
            }
        }   
}
```

---

```
C:\Jenkins\workspace\Run Test>powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "[Console]::OutputEncoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\CreateQAXml.ps1;EXIT $global:LastExitCode" 
    'powershell.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: What is `powershellCmd`, a custom function? Why don't you use the [`powershell`](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#powershell-powershell-script) step?

Comment: Since I need to give only a link to the script, I found such a function, and in function "powershell" I don’t understand how to transfer the full path to the file